# Maven assembly : bundle docs and sources jars

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module maven project. Each library module generates its own jar output:

```
Parent (Pom)
   |
   Library_01 (jar)
   |   output:
   |     |
   |     lib1.jar
   |     |
   |     lib1-docs.jar
   |     |
   |     lib1-sources.jar
   |
   Library_02 (jar)
   |   output:
   |     |
   |     lib2.jar
   |     |
   |     lib2-docs.jar
   |     |
   |     lib2-sources.jar
   |
   Distribution (pom) // uses assembly plug-in to assemble outputs of other modules here
       output:
         |
         lib1.jar
         |
         lib2.jar
```

I'm assembling other module's binaries in Distribution module exactly as explained in `maven-assembly-plugin`'s [documentation here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/module-binary-inclusion-simple.html). My POM's look exactly as in the tutorial.

It works the way shown in documentation. In package phase, assembly plugin collects both other module's jars in Distribution module. But as you can see, the other library modules are also configured to produce docs and source jars as well.

1. How do I configure assembly plugin to collect docs and sources jars of other modules also ?
2. Thinking about distribution, The above setup doesn't seem appropriate. I still end up with a bunch of jars for different libraries. Can classes,sources and docs of all the other modules each be combined into single jar file ?. Basically, I want 3 global jars (binary,docs and sources) to be distributed. How can this be achieved ?

Like:

```
   |
   Distribution (pom)
         |
         Global.jar (contains classes of Lib1 + Lib2)
         |
         Global-docs.jar (contains docs of Lib1 + Lib2)
         |
         Global-sources.jar (contains sources of Lib1 + Lib2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have gone through following options:

1. [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) : Builds combined binaries, may be sources too, but no javadocs. Also, very complicated.
2. [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) : Builds combined binaries and sources really easily, but no javadocs. Also, sources file name is hard to control.

So, simple approach I took is as follows:

Make sure all modules generate source jar. This can be done by enabling sources plug-in in parent pom, which is inherited by all modules:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Create a special "build" module to combine all other module's sources. This is done by using `maven-dependency-plugin`'s `unpack-dependencies` goal, with sources classifier. This means combining all other modules source as sources of this module.

Build module's pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example.product</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>build</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Build</name>

    <properties>
        <!--add comma separated artifact names from dependencies, to be included in unpacking-->
        <project.build.unpack_includes>sub-product</project.build.unpack_includes>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>sub-product</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${parent.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>sources</classifier>
                    <type>jar</type>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                    <includeArtifactIds>${project.build.unpack_includes}</includeArtifactIds>
                    <includes>**\/*.java</includes>
                    <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Now, build module compiles like any other project, generating all required jars.

Answer (score 1):

well, I'm not an expert but I do sth similar in a multi module project too. 
this is a parent's pom piece where specify the plugin and the documentation:

```
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>outputDirectory</name>
                            <value>${project.build.outputDirectory}</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>user.language</name>
                            <value>ca</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>user.country</name>
                            <value>ES</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>javac</executable>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>ISO-8859-15</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <detectLinks>true</detectLinks>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>aggregate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>site</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>ISO-8859-15</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <useUniqueVersions>false</useUniqueVersions>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <generateClient>false</generateClient>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- <configuration> <links> <link>http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/</link> 
                <link>http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/</link> <link>http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/</link> 
                <link>http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/</link> <link>http://www.easymock.org/api/easymock/2.5.2/</link> 
                <link>http://testng.org/javadocs/</link> <link>http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/</link> 
                <link>http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/mdocs1.6/</link> <link>http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pgdocs1.6/</link> 
                <link>http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/tspdocs1.6/</link> </links> </configuration> -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>agregar</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>pre-site</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: You defined javadoc plugin twice?